# Por que esse algoritmo em C esta retornando valores errados?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
Desenvolva um algoritmo que leia 2 vetores de 10 elementos inteiros cada.
Em seguida, calcule a soma desses vetores, guarde o resultado em um
terceiro vetor e escreva o resultado
*/
int main(void)
{
  int vetorA[10];
  int vetorB[10];
  int vetorAB[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     printf("Digite um valor vetorA[%d]:",i);
     scanf("%d", &vetorA);
  }
  printf("\n");

  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    printf("Digite um valor vetorB[%d]:",j);
    scanf("%d", &vetorB);
  }
  printf("\n");

  for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    vetorAB[k] = vetorA[k] + vetorB[k];
  }

  for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
     printf("%d\n",vetorAB[z]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

O esperado seria tipo vetorAB[0] = vetorA[0] + vetorB[0] por exemplo mas esta retornando valores diferentes

Comment: Isso é um erro de digitação. As falta a posição na leitura dos dois vetores que devia ser `scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);` e `scanf("%d", &vetorB[i]);` respetivamente

Comment: obrigado ! nem notei

Answer (score 0):

Sua entrada está incorreta.
Nos dois primeiros laços de repetição, você está lendo o vetor A e B, respectivamente, algo assim:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    scanf("%d", &vetorA);
```

Seu scanf está recebendo um inteiro do fluxo padrão de entrada (no momento, seu teclado) e gravando o resultado no endereço de memória de vetorA, ou seja, no início do seu vetor que corresponde ao endereço de memória de vetorA[0]. Para corrigir isto, use o artifício da sua variável contadora para iterar sobre o vetor:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    scanf("%d", &vetorA[i]);
```

Dica: você está usando uma variável INT para cada laço, se você usar apenas uma, além de seu código ficar mais enxuto e bonito, ele ficará mais simples, experimente declarar a variável int i no início do programa, e usar ela em todos os laços (eles nunca vão conflitar por que eles executam um por vez, e por conta da declaração `for (i = 0; ...`, i sempre voltará para 0 quando um novo laço começar.